# Which regex pattern used to check date format 'dd-mm-yyyy'

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to check whether the date format is in **dd-mm-yyyy**. So that I can change it.

```
if (date.match("/^\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}$/")) //dd-mm-yyyy
return value.replace(/(\d\d)\-(\d\d)\-(\d{4})/, "$3-$2-$1"); //yyyy-mm-dd`
```

So which pattern is correct for it, to check the date format.

Comment: Use a date library, not regex. You cannot define a useful pattern for valid dates, you can only check if the values are *sort of* correct and if they use the correct symbols. But you cannot easily validate stuff like `30-02-2019` or `31-04-2019`

Comment: If you get rid of the double quotes around your regex (the first one in the if condition), which turn them into mere strings, it might already work how you intended it to do.

Comment: @VLAZ When all you want to do is check if a string is in a specified simple format, there is no need to load a library. For other types of date-manipulations, a library probably makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the regexp below I check that the day is 01-31, month is 01-12 and year is 1900-2099. If so, the replace will happen and will result in yyyy-mm-dd.

```js
function change(input) {
 return input.replace(/^((?:0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))-((?:0[1-9]|1[012]))-((?:19\d\d|20\d\d))$/,"$3-$2-$1");
}

function check(input) {
  // If you want to accept year 0000-9999, replace "(?:19\d\d|20\d\d)" with "\d{4}"
  return /^(?:0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])-(?:0[1-9]|1[012])-(?:19\d\d|20\d\d)$/.test(input)
}
console.log(change("01-10-1922"));

console.log("01-10-2011",check("01-10-2011")); // true
console.log("2011-10-01",check("2011-10-01")); // false
console.log("01-21-2011",check("01-21-2011")); // false
```

This will not validate the date. For example it will happily accept February 31, April 31 etc, but it will not try to convert February 32 or January 00, or month 13...

Comment: input date for me will always be correct. I just have to check what format it is in

Comment: @AD There is no need to first check it and then use replace with an almost identical regex. It can all happen in the replace-regexp, since it will only replace something if the regexp match. If it doesn't match it will return the string unaltered. If you just want to test if it is in the expected format, you can use the same regexp, or a little simpler (without grouping) `/^(?:0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])-(?:0[1-9]|1[012])-(?:19\d\d|20\d\d)$/.test("04-10-2019")`

Comment: Thanks, much needed. Handles date, month and year with their values and position in dd-mm-yyyy

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work for you

```
if (date.match(/^(\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2})-(\d{4})$/)){
      return date.replace(/(\d\d)\-(\d\d)\-(\d{4})/, "$3-$2-$1");
}
```

The replacing you've done will work but you should also consider the date x-y-zzzz in dd-mm-yyyy or assert for the input to be padded with zeros on the left, if the date is being extracted from some source which follows the 'x' pattern instead of '0x' the above regex should handle that too